# Can I use WSO2 Microgateway with any RestAPI or Publisher support without CLI?

Tags: wso2, grpc, wso2-api-manager

I am interested in gRPC, so I researched and test some kind of Microgateway tools such as Kong, Gloo, and WSO2 microgateway.

WSO2 microgateway was quite awesome and suitable for me.
However I had to use only CLI while creating and testing stuffs.
My question is how  I can deploy and manage APIs witout CLI.

Any tips or plan to use Microgateway without CLI?
I mean, RestAPI or Publisher support will be a perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the wso2 Microgateway toolkit(Microgateway CLI tool) to generate the API artifacts. The responsibility of the toolkit is to create a Microgateway project and after that generate an executable jar file for the Microgateway runtime. **There is no other way to generate the Microgateway project and artifacts without CLI**. To manage generated Microgateway projects you can use some version control system like Git and create some automation for the deployment.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
I think I should find another way.

Comment: you are welcome. Btw why you can't use the CLI. ?

Comment: Actually I can use the toolkit. But unfortunately my customers can't handle the CLI, even though they have used WSO2 APIM for a long time.
that's why I am trying to find and offer more seamless managing environments (gRPC MicroGateway + APIM publisher or RestAPI) for them.